# Avoid singleton when dependency injection won't work

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have two content providers, let's call them data and meta. Data calls on meta during its write operations to write some metadata. Under the hood, though, both work on the same database, and to avoid deadlocks during transactions, they have to be on the same database *connection*, as well.

At the moment, I achieve this by using the singleton design pattern for my `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass, but this makes it hard to mock out for testing (as it is, my tests write to the same database as the app itself = bad).

Normally I would solve this with dependency injection **but** the framework relies on the presence of a no argument constructor to instantiate the providers, so I can't go that way.

Theoretically, I could change my `SQLiteOpenHelper` class to be a singleton map, mapping from (weak references of) `Context` to instances, but that seems even worse.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: "Avoid singleton"? I like how that title starts!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a no-args constructor you can use setter(s) to add needed dependencies.

An example of Singleton holder is

```
interface Service {
}

enum ServceHolder { /* no instance */;
    static volatile Service service;
    public static Service getService() { return service; }
    public static void setService(Service s) { service = s; }
}
```

Comment: True, but the framework creates the providers under the hood, so I don't have access to them when it does.

Comment: @chris so you need to explore the options your framework supports.  How about a singleton holder which can be overwritten.

Comment: sorry I think I worded that badly...by "framework" I mean the Android framework. Can you elaborate on the singleton holder? I googled it but it seems to only address lazy vs eager creation of the singleton, and I'm already lazily creating it.

Comment: @chris I have added an example which allows you to mock a service which is a singleton.

Comment: I see. So in my test setup I would just initialize it with `DbHelper.Holder.setHelper(new DbHelper(getMockContext())`? But where do I set the held instance for the actual app? Do I need to subclass `Application` and do it in `onCreate`?

Comment: @chris you want to do it as early as possible.

Comment: There's something that puzzles me about this: Even with my original singleton implementation, why does this happen at all? When doing the test run, shouldn't my helper class get initialized, so the initial singleton instance would be null? Then when I first access it, it should get initialized. Debugging shows me that the static initializer is executed before the test, and `Log.d("Init", "" + instance)` outputs "null". However, debugging also shows that on the first call to `getInstance()`, `instance` has magically been reset to something very much not null... Do you have a hint for me why?

Comment: @chris when you are using the debugger, it changes the order of evaluation slightly because you are doing things like displaying the contents of variables.  Also if the field is being initialised by another thread, you can get very different order of execution with a debugger.

Comment: I finally figured out the "magic" on that as well. When unit testing, it sets up the regular app before any of the tests, which included initializing the content providers. That's where the "bogus" instance came from. I just _really_ wish there was some way to attach data to contexts in Android to have it globally available, like the system services. You don't by any chance know of a way to do that...? I searched but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this a different way now. 
My solution involves storing the accessing the `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance in a package private field and subsequently only accessing it through a lazily initializing getter that will check with its "buddy" content provider for an existing instance.

```
protected SQLiteOpenHelper getHelper() {
    if (dbHelper == null) {
        ContentProviderClient client = getContext()
                .getContentResolver()
                .acquireContentProviderClient(MetaContentProvider.AUTHORITY);
        try {
            MetaContentProvider buddy = (MetaContentProvider) client.getLocalContentProvider();

            if (buddy.dbHelper != null) {
                dbHelper = buddy.dbHelper;
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException x /* Wasn't a MetaContentProvider */) {
        } catch (NullPointerException x /* MetaContentProvider is unavailable (it's client was null) */) {
        } finally {
            client.release();
        } 
    }
    if (dbHelper == null) {
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(getContext());
    }
    return dbHelper;
}
```

Is this a pretty solution? By no means. It's a fairly ugly travesty, producing a hidden dependency much like the singleton pattern, and it only works in the first place because both providers are in the same package (although that is not that unusual).

It does, however, get rid of the singleton pattern altogether, while making sure that **there is only one shared `SQLiteOpenHelper` per context** - and this is the great advantage it has over the singleton pattern. Test code does not need to be modified at all anymore to steer the providers away from the production database - because the test is in a different context, it automatically requires a new shared helper. Moreover, it does not require exposing or introducing API only for testing purposes (something I am strongly opposed to).